# Removing duplicates using various condition in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a following data set

```
Id  Site    Date
1   A   01-01-2021
1   A   02-02-2021
1   A   08-06-2021
1   A   09-06-2021
2   B   03-03-2021
2   B   08-05-2021
2   B   10-07-2021
2   B   15-07-2021
```

In the above data set I want to remove duplicates based on several condition-
1.If date is less than 08JUNE2021 AND Site is A then keep the id with most recent date

2.If date is greater than 08June2021 and site is A then keep id with most recent date

3.If date is less than 09JULY2021 and site is B then keep id with most recent date

4.If date is greater than 09JULY2021 and site is B keep id with most recent date

And after the condition data set which I want is given below

```
Id  site    Date
1   A   02-02-2021
1   A   09-06-2021
2   B   08-05-2021
2   B   15-07-2021
```

I had tried the code for the data

```
proc sql; create table want as select * from (select ,count() as count, case when count()>1 and Date>"07JUN2021"d then 1 when count()>1 and Date<"07JUN2021"d then 2 else count(*) end as flag from z group by id) where site="A"; quit; run;
```

Comment: What is the question ? Have you written or tried any code yet ? Have you checked with Abhishek about the assignment ?

Comment: Yes we are working on the same problem but not able to find the solution. Actually in table one we have two rounds of data for site A and B ,site A round two data collection was started after 07JUNE2021 and for site B after 08JULY2021.I want to keep both rounds data for site A and site B with most recent date. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Tried this code                                                                                                            
proc sql;
create table want as select * from (select *,count(*) as count,
case when count(*)>1 and Date>"07JUN2021"d then 1 
when count(*)>1 and Date<"07JUN2021"d then 2 else count(*) end as flag from z
group by id)
where site="A";
quit;
run;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Comments is not the place to add more to the question.  Amend your question by editing it and place your tried code there.

Comment: Ok sorry I am new to stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I like for this is to create a 'group' variable that allows you to identify groupings.  Here I show doing that with an informat.  This is a good way to do it if you always only have two groups ('before' date and 'after' date); if you have more than two groups, there are other options. Also note I assume you mean less than and (not less than); if you actually want to explicitly exclude June 8th records for Site A, then this will need some adaptation.

```
data have;
input Id  Site $ Date :ddmmyy10.;
format date date9.;
datalines;
1   A   01-01-2021
1   A   02-02-2021
1   A   08-06-2021
1   A   09-06-2021
2   B   03-03-2021
2   B   08-05-2021
2   B   10-07-2021
2   B   15-07-2021
;;;;
run;

*Create an informat that maps each site to the pivot date;
proc format;
  invalue site_datei
  'A' = '08JUN2021'd
  'B' = '09JUL2021'd
  ;
run;

* Now compare the date to the pivot date for that site, and assign group based on that result;
data for_sort;
  set have;
  group = ifn(date lt input(site,site_datei.),1,2);
run;
```

Now you can do many things to get the max value per group - here is a SQL solution since you seem to prefer that.

```
proc sql;
  select id, site, group, max(date) format=date9. from for_sort group by id, site, group;
quit;
```

This could have been done in a single SQL query, but I recommend against that unless there's significant performance considerations (and in that case, I even MORE strongly recommend against SQL!).

Comment: For reference, the suggested method if you have more groupings is to create one format per site, named with the site, that has the date ranges of interest mapped to group values.  Then use the `putn' function which lets you use a numeric function based on a value you construct!

Comment: Here in example I mentioned only two ids 1 and 2 but in real data I have many ids like this say from 1 to 99 then what I need to change in the code?

Comment: If it's just lots of IDs, then nothing - this already works fine for the separate IDs.  But if different IDs implies different Sites, then you'd have to add more to the informat - one line per site  with the new pivot date for each site.

Comment: Yes there are different ids for different sites and ids are in combination of 6 numeric numbers.

Comment: From what you've said, ID doesn't really matter, but site does - you just want unique results for each ID, right?  Then the ID value is irrelevant, this groups by that fine.  Just make sure each site is represented in the informat.

Comment: Code ran perfectly fine .Thanks again for your effort